# RNDecryptor : error while decrypting data encrypted by PHP (mcrypt_encrypt)

Tags: php, iphone, ios, mcrypt

I have a problem ... and It kills me

Below is my code:

PHP

1-I did not use any kind of pre-padding and generated the IV with 16 bytes.

2-I forced the pbkdf2 function to return 8 bytes for key & hmacKey

```
$key = "myKey";
$plainText = "iphone";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_RAND);
$keySalt = '12345678';
$hmacSalt = '12345678';
$_key = pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $keySalt, 10000, 8, true);
$_hmacKey = pbkdf2('SHA1', $key, $hmacSalt, 10000, 8, true);
$cipherText = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_key, $plainText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$dataWithoutHMAC = chr(2).chr(1).$keySalt.$hmacSalt.$iv.$cipherText;
```

3-first try I passed the cipher text to the hash_hmac

```
$data = base64_encode($dataWithoutHMAC.hash_hmac('SHA256',$cipherText,$_hmacKey, true));
```

and I got "et.robnapier.RNCryptManager error -4301" while decrypting in iOS. "which mean too small buffer as I think"

4-second try I passed the header (chr(2).chr(1).$keySalt.$hmacSalt.$iv) + cipher text to the hash_hmac (but I got the same result for the first try [-4301])

```
$data = base64_encode($dataWithoutHMAC.hash_hmac('SHA256',$dataWithoutHMAC,$_hmacKey, true));
```

In iOS

```
decryptionError = nil;
NSData *fromPHPData = [@"AgExMjM0NTY3ODEyMzQ1Njc4WvrmgsFy6IoWNmm2hYL9N2jNVxU13Eo15cRyQRakRZ9WsjZ2CY/B5y4YkmG9uGdB2vHFpmpjsnm3O4d59Ex7Nw==" base64DecodedData];

NSData *fromPHPDecryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:fromPHPData withPassword:@"myKey" error:&decryptionError];

NSLog(@"decryptionError %@", decryptionError);
NSString *fromPHPEcryptedStr = [fromPHPDecryptedData base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@"data : %@", fromPHPEcryptedStr);
```

the error I got in iOS is : "The operation couldn’t be completed. (net.robnapier.RNCryptManager error -4301.)"

Comment: Thanks to [Rob][https://github.com/rnapier],

After he made some changes to his library he shared this [link][http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php]

Comment: Dude the links are broken, please update them.